# PHP wrong foreach code

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

What I have done wrong, foreach code written below, but it seems not working:

```
$custom = "8-1,1-1,4-1,";

foreach ($custom as $each_item) {
    $id = $each_item['id'];
    $quantity = $each_item['quantity'];
    $sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) {
        $product_name = $row["product_name"];
        $price = $row["price"];
    } }
```

What I have to change in this foreach code? Thanks

Comment: 1) `custom = '8-1,1-1,4-1';` is wrong (missing `$`). 2) You're iterating a string with `foreach`, and expecting the elements to be associative arrays 3) You're using `mysql_query` in an unsafe way _and_ that extension is deprecated

Comment: Show your actual `$custom` variable.

Comment: BeeBee: thanks for wanting to add an answer to this. However, we don't edit questions into answers - if you want to show how you solved it, please add that in a self-answer post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first line, custom is not a variable (could be copy and paste error)

```
$custom
```

Then you are splitting a string using can array operator, you need to split that string first using:

```
$custompieces = explode(",", $custom);
```

Then, you have declared $custom as $each_item, but you then appear to be trying to access a sub array that doesn't exist. $each_item[id] and $each_item[quantity] are not defined anywhere. I am guessing that you are trying to split the 8-1 into id-quantity, in which case you need to actually define those to be able to use them.

```
$pieces = explode("-", $each_item);
$id = $pieces[0];
$quantity = $pieces[1];
```

So your final code needs to be:

```
$custom = "8-1,1-1,4-1,";
$custompieces = explode(",", $custom);
foreach ($custompieces as $each_item) {
$pieces = explode("-", $each_item);
$id = $pieces[0];
$quantity = $pieces[1];
$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) {
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $price = $row["price"];
} }
```

Comment: great answer, but it prints out only last record from the string.

Comment: it will do because you are overwriting the output on each row. put your action inside the function

Comment: i, see. i've put action inside the function, and it now doubles last record's name and price, but quantity is empty. how could i solve this?

Comment: $custom = "8-1,1-1,4-1,";
$custompieces = explode(",", $custom);
foreach ($custompieces as $each_item) {
$pieces = explode("-", $each_item);
$id = $pieces[0];
$quantity = $pieces[1];
$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) {
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $price = $row["price"];
} 
/* put your action/echo using $quantity, $product_name and $price in here and uncomment */
}

Comment: everything would be okay, but this happens: http://imgur.com/xnX5h6q code: http://imgur.com/t9765NJ

Comment: well, as you only have 3 sets of data in your original $custom array, not quite sure where that 4th line is coming from.

Comment: unless you still have an echo outside of the code above.

Comment: full code: http://imgur.com/b1X6WUt breaking my head realy hard, cant find any mistake

Comment: add $message2 = ''; at top of file before your $custom declaration.

Comment: figured it out :) transformed your code a liltle bit, now works perfectly

Comment: glad it helped ;) if you could accept the answer i would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` is meant to be used to iterate over `array` but you are using it with a `string`.

So it is not working for you.